# Check if a value among a list exist in multiple column R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

**Problem**

I have a dataset with a lot of identical kind of variables which can contain the same values. I would like to check if among those variable, we can find at list one value among a list of values.

**Example**

Let say that we have a dataset with 3 variables of factor type `DAS1`, `DAS2`, `DAS3`.
The possible values for those variables are `c("0", "1", "x", "y")` (note that I'm not trying to differentiate numbers and letters. Consider every values as characters).

```
library(data.table)

start <- data.table::data.table(DAS1 = c("0","1","x","0","1","0","1"),
                       DAS2 = c("x","y","0","0","x","1","0"),
                       DAS3 = c("1","1","y","1","x","y","0"))
```

My objective is to find which row contain at least one observation of the values `"x"` or `"y"`.

```
result <- data.table::data.table(DAS1 = c("0","1","x","0","1","0","1"),
                       DAS2 = c("x","y","0","0","x","1","0"),
                       DAS3 = c("1","1","y","1","x","y","0"),
                       xy = c(T,T,T,F,T,T,F))
```

**Condition**

I really want to do it with the `data.table` package and not `dplyr` because I mostly use `data.table` and I don't like to switch between the two packages if it's not necessary.

**Answer by @lovalery**

```
start[, xy := apply(start[,c("DAS1", "DAS2", "DAS3")],1, function(x) any(x %in% c("x", "y")))][]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(data.table)

start[, xy := apply(start,1, function(x) any(x == "x" | x == "y"))][]
```

- Output

```r
#>    DAS1 DAS2 DAS3    xy
#> 1:    0    x    1  TRUE
#> 2:    1    y    1  TRUE
#> 3:    x    0    y  TRUE
#> 4:    0    0    1 FALSE
#> 5:    1    x    x  TRUE
#> 6:    0    1    y  TRUE
#> 7:    1    0    0 FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: your solution is a bit faster than `rowSums` according to `microbenchmark`

Comment: Almost perfect solution. Instead of `any(x == "x" | x == "y")` I used `any(x %in% c("x","y"))` (because I have actually a long list of values to check). Also, I have more variables in my dataset, and I would like to check the presence of values only on a list of variables. Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: @Kévin Legueult, thank you very much for your feedback. To answer your comment's request you could specify a vector of column names like this (here, the case where we just select the first two columns by name) : `start[, xy := apply(start[,c("DAS1", "DAS2")],1, function(x) any(x %in% c("x", "y")))][]` Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: @Kévin Legueult, you are welcome. Glad that I could help. If you want it to be even faster you can change `%in%` by the dedicated `data.table` function `%chin%`. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
> start[, xy := rowSums((.SD == "x") + (.SD == "y")) > 0][]
   DAS1 DAS2 DAS3    xy
1:    0    x    1  TRUE
2:    1    y    1  TRUE
3:    x    0    y  TRUE
4:    0    0    1 FALSE
5:    1    x    x  TRUE
6:    0    1    y  TRUE
7:    1    0    0 FALSE
```

or

```
> start[, xy := rowSums(Reduce(`+`, Map(`==`, c("x", "y"), list(.SD)))) > 0][]
   DAS1 DAS2 DAS3    xy
1:    0    x    1  TRUE
2:    1    y    1  TRUE
3:    x    0    y  TRUE
4:    0    0    1 FALSE
5:    1    x    x  TRUE
6:    0    1    y  TRUE
7:    1    0    0 FALSE
```